# how to change properties file according to rest api or unit test call from src/test/resources and src/main/resources

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, junit, properties, in-memory

I am creating a spring mvc application and during normal flow of an api, properties for database are taken from "application.properties" file in *src/main/resources* folder. Then I wrote the unit test cases for the same and created a file with the same name i.e. "application.properties"  in *src/test/resources* folder. The test cases were running fine earlier but now for the normal flow,now they are taking parameters from *src/test/resources* instead of taking only from *src/main/resources* .

> File Structure :
>   **DemoProject**
>
> |-src/main/resources/*application.properties*
>
> |-src/test/resources/*application.properties*

this is my hibernamteConfiguration file:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.akshay.pojos" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
     @Bean
     public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing under `source/test` will be included on the runtime classpath (outside of testing obviously) unless you have done something strange.

Comment: It is taking parameter from _src/test/resources/application.properties_ for unit test cases  and from _src/main/resources/application.properties_ for the normal rest api call

Comment: I am confused. What is the problem then?

Comment: I want to take properties from src/test/resources for the unit test case and src/main/resources for the normal fow of the rest api. It is now taking from src/test/resources for both the flow